# One button change more than one colour

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need with one button to change text color, but not once, i need that the button at first press change text in black, at the second press change text in blue, at the third... and more and more.

For change color i use these function

```
- (IBAction)SwitchColor:(id)sender{
    timerLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

But i am too newbie to understand how make what i need.

For the image i use these:

```
- (IBAction)SwitchImages:(id)sender{
    fondo.tag++;
    [fondo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background%d.jpg",1+(fondo.tag%5)]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like:

```
- (IBAction)SwitchColor:(id)sender{
    timerLabel.tag++;
    if (timerLabel.tag == 1) {
        timerLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else if (timerLabel.tag == 2) {
        timerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } // etc
}
```

In reality, I wouldn't use `tag` for that though, nor for the `SwitchImages` method you've shown. I would have two local variables which are initialised to `0` in `viewDidLoad` and then use those in each of the switch methods to work out what to do next and then increment the variable. Presumably you'll also want to wrap back round to `0` at some point as well.

Comment: Thanks works fine and now i understand that the mistake is not the code but the concept!

Answer (score 1):

Check this it uses random function to show color and Popover effect on iphone as well https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView